# Org publish does not load Latex packages

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, org-publish, mathjax

I need the following two packages and I add them to my org file like this,

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{siunitx}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{cancel}
```

but this does not work. How can I fix this?

I tried with another package, it's strange, all instances work but one instance does not work. Screenshots below:

[image]

### [image]

Here's my setup file:

```
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(

("org-notes"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "org"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
 :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
 :auto-preamble nil
 :html-preamble "<div id=\"navbar\"> <ul>
  <li><a href=\"index.html\">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href=\"/iletisim.html\">İletişim</a></li>
  <li><a href=\"/hakkinda.html\">Hakkında</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</div>
"
 )

("org-static"
 :base-directory "~/org/"
 :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
 :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
 :recursive t
 :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
 )

("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))

       ;; ... add all the components here (see below)...

      ))
```

This is the header and latex in the org file:

```
#+SETUPFILE: ~/.emacs.d/org-templates/level-0.org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{siunitx}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{cancel}


\begin{align*}
    \frac{\text{A}}{\text{B}} &= \frac{\frac{\text{G} \times 10.64 \times d \times m}{(8.85)^2}}{\frac{\text{G} \times (41,800,000)^3 \times d' \times m}{(6.41 \times 41,800,000)^2}}\\
    \\
            &= \frac{\cancel{\text{G}}\times 10.64 \times d \times \cancel{m}}{(8.85)^2} \;\frac{(6\times 41,800,000)^2}{\cancel{\text{G}} \times (41,800,000)^3 \times d'\times \cancel{m} }\\
            \\
            &= 10.64 \times \left (\frac{6}{8.85}\right )^2 \times \frac{\cancel{(41,800,000)^2}}{(41,800,000)\cancel{^3}} \times \frac{d}{d'}\\
            \\
            &= \left (\frac{6}{8.85}\right )^2 \times \frac{10.64}{41,800,000} \times \frac{d}{d'}\\
            \\
            &= 0.4596380 \times \num{2.54e-7} \times \frac{d}{d'}\\
            \\
            &=\num{1.16998e-7}\frac{d}{d'}\\
            \\
            &=\frac{1}{\num{1.16998e-7}} = 8547088\times\frac{d'}{d}\\
\end{align*}
```

This is how the published pdf looks like:

[image]

Comment: I would suggest that you add to your question a minimal Org mode file that exhibits the problem (perhaps including just the section the produced the output above, but make sure it's complete: e.g. it should include all the keyword stuff at the top). That will allow people who might be inclined to answer, to actually cut and paste the example and try it on their own. That increases your chances of getting an answer exponentially :-)

Comment: Thanks, I added the header and Latex code.

Comment: This works fine for me. Are you sure you have the LaTeX cancel and siunitx packages installed?

Comment: Except that you have that `#+SETUPFILE: ` which nobody else has :-) We'll see whether it works without it. In the meantime, check the `*Org PDF LaTeX Output*` buffer to see if there are any errors. Also check the TeX file that the exporter produces to make sure it looks reasonable. You might even want to compile it from the command line: that's a useful debugging technique.

Comment: @Tyler That might be the problem, how do I install these packages? I thought org publish took care of that. I tried the latex code in Overleaf and it works fine.

Comment: @NickD I publish with a macro, this time I tried with the exporter and it installed the missing packages, but it still does not use them. Maybe I need to restart emacs?

Comment: Restarting didn't help

Comment: When I export to Latex, instead of publishing, it all works fine! How can I fix publishing as well?

Comment: What is in your setup file?

Comment: Publishing is exporting, plus moving exported files to various places (roughly). So if exporting works, publishing should work. But as @Tyler asks, show us your config file for publishing. BTW, Org mode does not install anything: e.g. I had to `dnf install texlive-cancel` on my Fedora system. You might have to do something similar. I have no idea what Overleaf does and why it works. As always, I suggest you try from the command line: `pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex` with your exported file - or `xelatex` or `lualatex` or whatever engine Org mode is using.  Check `org-latex-pdf-process`.

Comment: @Tyler I added my setup file.

Comment: So you are exporting to HTML, not to PDF - right? IOW, those images you posted are from your browser?  If that's the case, you are probably using Mathjax for the math part and probably Mathjax does not know about `\cancel` or `\mathsrc`. See https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/index.html

Comment: Great, thanks. From that page, I added `\(\require{cancel}\)` and the code worked.

Comment: BTW, the instance of `\mathscr` that doesn't work is because you misspelled it `\mathsrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize and amplify the discussion in the comments: the OP was trying to publish to HTML, not to PDF: that became clear after he posted his `org-publish-project-alist` which specifies `org-html-publish-to-html` as the publishing function. In that case (LaTeX math in the Org mode file that is being exported to HTML), the default method of rendering the math is by using Mathjax: do `C-h i g (org)math formatting in HTML export`).

[Mathjax](https://www.mathjax.org/) is a Javascript display engine for math, so it works in all browsers. It knows a whole lot about LaTeX, but it does not know everything - in particular, if you use a LaTeX package (like `cancel.sty` e.g.) that `Mathjax` does not know about, you have to teach Mathjax to use it. What you have to do is described in [this page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/index.html)
which you probably should bookmark if you are using LaTeX math in Org mode files.

The simplest thing that you can do (which is what the OP describes in a comment) is to add an inline "math" expression to your Org mode file that tells Mathjax to "require" the `cancel` package:

```org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{siunitx}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{cancel}

* Foo


\( \require{cancel} \)


\[
(6.41\times 41800000)^2 = \frac{\cancel{G}\times 10.64\times d \times \cancel{m}}{(8.85)^2}
\]
```

(don't try to make any sense of the equation: it is meaningless - if you want you can try with OP's complete source, but I set the test up before he had posted that, so I just copied fragments out of his images. The important thing is that the `\cancel`s are rendered incorrectly without the `\require` and they are rendered correctly with it.)

BTW, you can test the above by just exporting to HTML: you don't have to have a publishing setup. Publishing is just "export with some copying/moving around of files afterwards" (roughly), so using just `export` to begin with can help with your debugging without having to deal with additional complications: export to an HTML file and then use a `file:///path/to/foo.html` URL to examine it.

One problem with this solution is that it breaks PDF export (try it), because `\require` isn't LaTeX, despite appearances. It is a trigger to `Mathjax` to do something and LaTeX complains about an undefined control sequence (although it does produce a PDF file with the additional word `cancel` in it, a remnant of the `\require`). To fix that, just make sure that the `\require` is *only* used in HTML export:

```org
...
#+begin_export HTML
\( \require{cancel} \)
#+end_export
...
```

But if you are going to use the `cancel` package often, you might want to teach Mathjax how to use it once and for all, so you don't have to `\require` anything in your Org mode file.

The Org manual, in the `Math formatting in HTML export` section (see above for how to get there), says that you can add:

```org
#+HTML_MATHJAX: cancel.js noErrors.js
```

to your Org mode file and that that will load the `cancel.js` and `noError.js` extensions to Mathjax: AFAICT this does *NOT* work. I also looked at the code and saw nothing to suggest that this is implemented. I'll post a doc bug on the ML.

What *does* work is adding the following to your init file *after* loading `ox-html`:

```
(with-eval-after-load "ox-html"
   (setq org-html-mathjax-template 
      (concat org-html-mathjax-template "
<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook(\"TeX Jax Ready\",function () {
  MathJax.Hub.Insert(MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.macros,{
    cancel: [\"Extension\",\"cancel\"],
    bcancel: [\"Extension\",\"cancel\"],
    xcancel: [\"Extension\",\"cancel\"],
    cancelto: [\"Extension\",\"cancel\"]
  });
});
</script>
")))
```

This Javascript code then gets added to the HTML file and loads the `cancel.js` extension, which lets Mathjax know about `\cancel` and related macros.

See the doc string of the variable with `C-h v org-html-mathjax-template` but be aware that it's just a string: a big blob of Javascript code that initializes and configures Mathjax. All that the Org mode HTML exporter does is replace a few placeholders with values from the variable `org-html-mathjax-options` (which see) and add the whole thing to the HTML file. For more details on the Javascript code, you will have to consult the [Mathjax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/).

Comment: I didn't realize it causes problems with PDF export, thanks.